# Почему возвращает ошибку при доступе к свойству родительского класса?

Tags: php

Пример по книге: "Поскольку свойство $price объявлено в классе ShopProduct , а не в BookProduct, попытка в приведенном выше коде (класс BookProduct" `function getPrice () {return $this->price}`) получить к нему доступ закончится неудачей.
Чтобы решить эту проблему, нужно объявить свойство $price защищенным
(p r o t e c t e d) и тем самым предоставить доступ к нему дочерним классам."

```
<?php

class ShopProduct {

    public $title;
    public $producerMainName;
    public $producerFirstName;
    protected $price;
    public $discount = 0;

    function __construct ($title, $firstName, $mainName, $price, $discount) { // конструктор

        $this -> title              = $title; // через $this обращаюсь к свойству этого класса title и присваиваю ему значение (аргумент), которое прилетит в переменную $title, когда вызовется метод конструктора (вызывается при создании нового объекта)
        $this -> producerFirstName  = $firstName;
        $this -> producerMainName   = $mainName;
        $this -> price              = $price;
        $this -> discount           = $discount;

    }

    /*
        Meтoд  __construct ( ) вызывается,  когда создается объект с помощью оператора new.
        Значения всех перечисленных аргументов передаются конструктору.
        Благодаря конструктору, создание экземпляров класса ShopProduct и определение значений их свойств выполняются в одном операторе.
    */

    function getProducer () { // метод. возвр. имя и фам автора
        return "{$this -> producerFirstName} " .
                "{$this -> producerMainName}";
    }

    function getSummaryLine () { // метод возвращает название альбома (или книги); имя, фамилию автора
        $base = "{$this -> title} ( {$this -> producerMainName}, ";
        $base .= "{$this -> producerFirstName} )";
        return $base;
    }

    function setDiscount ( $num ) { // метод. задать скидку
        $this -> discount = $num;
    }

    function getPrice () {  // метод, который принимает во внимание установленную скидку (=> цену и скидку)
        return ($this -> price/* - $this -> discount*/);
    }

}



                /* Класс CDProduct (дочерний) расширяет возможности класса ShopProduct */

class CDProduct extends ShopProduct {

    function __construct ($title, $firstName, $mainName, $price) {

        parent:: __construct($title, $firstName, $mainName, $price);    // Вызвать мeтoд __construct ( ) родительского класса
            $this -> playLength = $playLength;

    }

    function getPlayLength() { // метод. возвращает время звучания
        return $this -> playLength;
    }

    function getSummaryLine () { // метод. возвращает название альбома; имя, фамилию автора и время звучания
        $base = "{$this -> title} ( {$this -> producerMainName}, ";
        $base .= "{$this -> producerFirstName} )";
        $base .= ": Время звучания - {$this -> playLength}";
        return $base;
    }

}

                /* Класс BookProduct (дочерний) */

class BookProduct extends ShopProduct {

    function getNumberOfPages () {  // метод. вернуть количество страниц этого ($this) класса
        return $this -> numPages;
    }

    function getSummaryLine () {    // метод. возвращает название книги; имя, фамилию автора и количество страниц
        $base = "{$this -> title} ( {$this -> producerMainName}, ";
        $base .= "{$this -> producerFirstName} )";
        $base .= ": {$this -> numPages} стр.";
        return $base;
    }

    function getPrice () {  
        return ($this -> price);
    }
}

$product = new BookProduct ("Игра престолов", "Мартин", "Джордж", "20 $", "10");
echo $product -> price;
```

Comment: `echo $product -> price;` вы пытаетесь из **объекта** `product` вызвать price. Последняя строка вот на неё и ругается

Comment: "...Чтобы решить эту проблему, нужно объявить свойство $price защищенным (p r o t e c t e d) и тем самым предоставить доступ к нему дочерним классам."   Свойство price вызывается из дочернего класса, которому предоставлен доступ к нему. Следуя логике написанного - должно работать. Но нет!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Защищённые свойства (`protected`) недоступны снаружи класса так же как и приватные (`private`),  но в отличие от последних, к ним можно получить доступ внутри классов-потомков.

У PHP хорошая документация на русском языке (http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php), обращайтесь к ней, когда затрудняетесь понять автора учебника.

Comment: Подсказали, что нужно вызывать как метод, а не как свойство. Вот так: echo $product->getPrice(); тогда все ок!

Comment: Хоть дочерний класс и наследует свойство price, из внешнего кода его вызвать нельзя. - Это идет в разрез с инструкцией в книге, немного запутанно. Спасибо Вам